Fluter,Questions about real-time sound output through Bluetooth BLE
I am a junior developer who has just started using Flutter.
I want to receive sound in real time from a Bluetooth device and output it on a mobile phone device.
I confirmed the Bluetooth connection and received PCM data from the Bluetooth device, but I ran into difficulties during the printing process.
I tried finding and using packages such as flutter_sound, audio_streamer, and flutter_pcm_sound, but I was unable to solve the problem because there were not many reference materials for real-time processing.
PCM data comes in List format with values with indices of 130 to 160.
Please give me advice on how to resolve this.
p.s The sentences may not be accurate due to the use of Google Translator.
Example of data received :
[26, 161, 3, 0, 154, 154, 153, 152, 136, 135, 120, 103, 103, 103, 103, 102, 118, 118, 103, 102, 101, 101, 101, 85, 85, 102, 119, 137, 171, 204, 188, 203, 203, 204, 170, 186, 170, 152, 118, 66, 66, 52, 52, 37, 68, 53, 69, 68, 85, 101, 119, 136, 170, 203, 203, 203, 204, 188, 172, 171, 188, 187, 187, 188, 170, 170, 153, 152, 118, 85, 67, 65, 68, 52, 52, 52, 68, 53, 68, 68, 84, 101, 119, 136, 154, 170, 202, 187, 202, 202, 187, 188, 171, 201, 186, 201, 170, 186, 170, 154, 153, 153, 136, 120, 104, 118, 134, 118, 119, 103, 104, 102, 103, 102, 102, 85, 85, 69, 67, 67, 68, 52, 67, 84, 85, 86, 119, 136, 154, 171, 203, 189, 202, 188, 187, 188, 187, 202, 186, 186, 186, 169, 136, 118, 102, 85, 67, 67, 52, 67, 68, 52, 67, 69, 68, 84, 86, 103, 120, 137, 154, 171, 187, 202]
[26, 161, 3, 0, 152, 136, 152, 152, 136, 136, 136, 120, 120, 104, 119, 104, 103, 104, 102, 118, 118, 134, 119, 120, 120, 135, 137, 137, 152, 153, 153, 137, 153, 152, 152, 152, 136, 135, 135, 134, 134, 134, 103, 102, 118, 118, 103, 103, 103, 119, 120, 120, 136, 136, 153, 153, 154, 153, 154, 153, 154, 153, 153, 152, 136, 120, 119, 104, 87, 102, 102, 102, 102, 86, 102, 102, 118, 118, 134, 136, 120, 136, 137, 153, 169, 169, 170, 154, 154, 153, 169, 152, 136, 134, 135, 118, 118, 102, 118, 102, 103, 102, 118, 134, 134, 136, 120, 136, 137, 152, 153, 153, 137, 137, 152, 152, 136, 136, 120, 120, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 119, 134, 136, 104, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 135, 136, 120, 135, 136, 136, 135, 136, 120, 120, 104, 119, 118, 134, 119, 103, 103, 103, 103, 119, 119, 134, 152, 136, 137, 154, 154, 154, 154]
[26, 161, 3, 0, 120, 120, 136, 137, 153, 154, 153, 169, 154, 154, 153, 153, 152, 152, 135, 135, 120, 103, 104, 102, 102, 118, 103, 103, 103, 118, 134, 135, 120, 120, 120, 136, 135, 136, 136, 136, 135, 136, 120, 104, 134, 135, 119, 134, 135, 135, 135, 136, 120, 136, 136, 152, 136, 136, 137, 136, 152, 152, 136, 136, 136, 135, 135, 134, 134, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 103, 103, 103, 104, 104, 120, 120, 136, 137, 153, 153, 153, 168, 154, 153, 153, 169, 137, 136, 136, 135, 134, 134, 118, 118, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 103, 103, 104, 119, 136, 136, 153, 154, 154, 170, 154, 154, 169, 154, 153, 136, 136, 120, 104, 104, 102, 118, 118, 103, 102, 133, 118, 118, 134, 119, 120, 120, 120, 136, 121, 136, 137, 137, 137, 136, 136, 136, 136, 135, 136, 104, 134, 134, 134, 135, 119, 118, 135, 119, 134, 136, 135, 136, 136]
[26, 161, 3, 0, 135, 136, 136, 153, 153, 153, 154, 137, 169, 169, 154, 153, 152, 136, 135, 119, 118, 118, 118, 102, 102, 103, 102, 103, 102, 119, 104, 104, 119, 136, 120, 136, 137, 153, 153, 153, 169, 153, 169, 153, 153, 153, 136, 120, 104, 103, 118, 103, 102, 103, 102, 118, 119, 104, 104, 104, 135, 136, 136, 136, 153, 137, 153, 136, 137, 136, 136, 136, 135, 135, 135, 120, 104, 119, 119, 120, 104, 104, 120, 104, 120, 120, 120, 120, 135, 136, 135, 136, 136, 120, 136, 135, 135, 120, 104, 118, 135, 118, 134, 134, 135, 120, 120, 120, 136, 136, 136, 136, 137, 137, 136, 152, 136, 136, 136, 136, 120, 120, 119, 119, 119, 103, 103, 102, 118, 102, 102, 102, 118, 118, 134, 135, 136, 136, 137, 153, 170, 154, 170, 154, 154, 154, 153, 153, 136, 135, 134, 134, 119, 103, 102, 103, 102, 103, 102, 102, 118, 119, 104, 104]
[26, 161, 3, 0, 134, 134, 134, 134, 136, 120, 120, 136, 135, 136, 137, 136, 136, 136, 136, 135, 136, 119, 134, 134, 134, 119, 119, 103, 104, 102, 134, 134, 135, 136, 136, 136, 153, 153, 153, 154, 153, 153, 153, 152, 136, 135, 134, 135, 118, 119, 102, 118, 103, 102, 118, 103, 103, 103, 119, 120, 120, 120, 136, 153, 153, 153, 169, 154, 169, 169, 169, 153, 153, 136, 120, 104, 103, 102, 118, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 103, 102, 118, 134, 134, 136, 120, 136, 137, 153, 154, 154, 154, 153, 169, 169, 153, 153, 136, 136, 119, 134, 134, 119, 103, 103, 103, 103, 134, 119, 119, 120, 120, 120, 120, 136, 136, 136, 135, 136, 136, 135, 136, 135, 135, 120, 104, 119, 134, 135, 120, 104, 120, 120, 120, 135, 136, 135, 136, 152, 136, 136, 136, 136, 136, 120, 119, 119, 118, 118, 118, 118, 103, 103, 103, 118, 134, 135, 134, 136]
